# UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath: not called in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

So the code works perfectly in iOS 6. However when I run it on iOS 7 device, the collectionView doesn't populate items and remains empty. I have found that:

```
(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

doesn't even get called.

Here is the code I create the collectionView from

```
ItemOptionListCollectionViewController *mv1 =[[ItemOptionListCollectionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GridOpcija" bundle:nil];
[mv1.collectionView registerClass:[OptionListCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellZaOpcije"];
[mv1.collectionView setDelegate:mv1];
mv1.collectionView.dataSource= mv1;
[mv1 insertListAsDataSource:[ol optionListItems]];
CGFloat scrollHeight = 0;
scrollHeight= ([ol.optionListItems count])*40;
mv1.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, height, modal.scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollHeight);
height +=mv1.view.frame.size.height;
[modal.scrollView addSubview:mv1.view];
```

And the ItemOptionListCollectionViewController is pretty plain, with not much but collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the value of `mv1.collectionView` at the point you set its data source?

Comment: have you checked if mv.collectionView actually references an object and is not nil (is the view actually already loaded)? Try moving that bit of a code where you set your dataSource and delegate to viewDidLoad inside your view controller... just a guess

Comment: I get the `<MenuItemCollectionView: 0x1623de00; baseClass = UICollectionView; frame = (0 0; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17072230>; layer = <CALayer: 0x15d79d30>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x170ae5c0>` just above the register class when I print mv1.collectionView. Also I have `self.collectionView.delegate = self;` and `self.collectionView.dataSource = self;` in viewDidLoad for ItemOptionListCollectionViewController.

Comment: Have you figured it out yet?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I spent a lot of time trying to figure it out, and I realized that it would be much easier to recode that part again which worked flawlessly. My guess it that some of the dimensions weren't matching and since iOS 7 is more restrictive it didn't want to display the collectionView.

Comment: Please add ItemOptionListCollectionViewController source code.